# TypeError with Django 1.8.13, but not with Django 1.9.6

Tags: django, wagtail

Trying to lower the requirements for a (working) Django/wagtail site from Django 1.9.6 to Django 1.8.13 i get a `TypeError` when trying to access any of my wagtail urls (don't matter if it's the admin interface or my site):

```
TypeError at /

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'builtins'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.8.13
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'builtins'

Exception Location:     /home/tombreit/projects/ecactj.org_wagtail/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in __init__, line 24
Python Executable:  /home/tombreit/projects/ecactj.org_wagtail/venv/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.5.1
Python Path:    

['/home/tombreit/projects/ecactj.org_wagtail',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/tombreit/projects/ecactj.org_wagtail/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

(Full error trace at http://dpaste.com/0T9AGGM)

Any ideas how get rid of this error?

This happens even after purging my `venv`, migrations, db. 
I would happily use Django 1.9.6, but that's not compatible with Python 3.3 which is the newest version offered by OpenShift.
Python 3.5 is used as my development environment because that's packaged for my Debian Testing/Stretch distribution, sadly there is no Python 3.3 available.

Another question would be if OpenShift is the right PaaS for an up to date Django/wagtail project...

Comment: First you appear to be testing about python 3.5 if your server only supports 3.3 shouldn't you use that instead? Secondly why not post the full error trace?

Comment: Thanks for these hints - question updated.

Comment: Does your own code mention `builtins` somewhere?

Comment: You're right - I use Django overextends which needed a template setting for Django 1.9+: https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends#project-configuration. After removing the `builtins` line, this error is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned error occured because I use Django overextends which needed a template setting for Django 1.9+: https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends#project-configuration.

And `builtins` were added in Django 1.9: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/

After removing the `builtins` line, this error is gone.